# Bootstrap Button doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a very simple landing page using Bootstrap v3.3.7 and I added a button, just like it shows on bootstrap. It words fine in Chrome but not in firefox. Any thoughts?

I'm using CDN in my header:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYYSY.png)

My HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row logo">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo-image" alt="Woodtech Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2>New <span class="bold">procurement technology</span><br />
            coming soon.
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>

            <a class="button-link" href="mailto:paulamouradp@gmail.com">
                <button type="button" class="contact-button btn btn-lg center-block contact-button">Contact us</button>
            </a>

        </div>
</div>
```

This is my landing in Chrome:
[enter image description here][2]

This is my landing in Firefox:
[enter image description here][3]

Comment: Fix your images please

Comment: Not sure why you are wrapping your button in a <a> tag. I would expect that to cause a problem.  You dont need to, you can just add the bootstrap button classes directly to the <a> and it will look like the a button.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out a solution (after 30 minutes!)

I was using Bootstrap CDN, and I downloaded Bootstrap's CSS instead and it worked just fine.  I hope this will be useful for you guys :)

Comment: Worked for me :)